# How to get PIDs waiting on a semaphore

Tags: linux, redhat, strace, ipc

If I strace a stuck process and see output of the form:

```
[gaius@redhat64 bin]$ strace -p 18185
Process 18185 attached - interrupt to quit
[ Process PID=18185 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
semop(458760, 0xffa00af0, 1
```

How would I find out the PID that last incremented the semaphore/that I am waiting for? I know about the `lpid` column in `ipcs -p` but that only works for shared memory segments.

My OS is RHEL 5.4 (Tikanga) on x86_64. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pid;
    if (argc != 2) return 1;
    pid = semctl(atoi(argv[1]), 0, GETPID);
    printf("%d\n", pid);
    return 0;
}
```

(I'm guessing here.)

Comment: semctl(2) man page is at http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/semctl/.  Arguments to the above program assume that you are passing in the ID of the semaphore obtained as "semid" in `ipcs -l`.  The GETPID is "the pid of the last process to perform an operation on semaphore number semnum.  The "0" argument is to pick the first semaphore under that `semid` although if there has been more than one created, you'll have to choose a different number.

Comment: `ipcs -s -i semid` may also show the same information.  `semid` is the same number given in `ipcs -l`.